# リストの末尾 n 個を取り出したい

Tags: python

Python のリスト `a` の末尾 n 個の要素を取り出したいです。ただし、n は任意の整数になりえ、n ≦ 0 のときは `[]`、n > len(a) のときは `a` を返すようにしたいです。

たとえば `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, `n = 2` だと、末尾 2 つの `[5, 6]` が返ってくるようにしたいです。

### 試したこと1

```
>>> a[-2:]
[5, 6]
```

スライスを作る方法 `a[m:]` で `m < 0` にすると末尾がとれます。ただしこれだと -len(a) < n ≦ 0 のときに動かしたいようには動きません。特に n = 0 のとき、末尾 0 個ではなく `a` 全体が返ってきてしまいます。

```
>>> # n > len(a) のときはきちんと a が返ってくる
... a[-10:]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> a[-15:]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> # -len(a) < n <= 0 のとき、[] が返ってこない
... a[0:]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> a[2:]
[3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> # n ≦ -len(a) のときは、きちんと [] が返ってくる
... a[10:]
[]
```

### 試したこと2

```
>>> a[len(a)-2:]
[5, 6]
```

明示的に何個目以降が必要なのかを計算してスライスを作ると末尾がとれます。ただしこれだと len(a) < n < 2*len(a) のときに動かしたいようには動きません。

```
>>> # len(a) < n < 2*len(a) のとき、a が返ってこない
... a[len(a)-10:]
[3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> # n >= 2*len(a) のとき、きちんと a が返ってくる
... a[len(a)-15:]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> # n <= 0 のとき、きちんと [] が返ってくる
... a[len(a)-0:]
[]
>>> a[len(a)+2:]
[]
>>> a[len(a)+10:]
[]
```

### 質問

上 2 つの方法はどちらも 0 < n ≦ len(a) のとき思ったように動作しますが、それ以外のときに思ったようには動いてくれません。

適当な関数を作って if 文で n を場合分けすれば[上手く動かせます](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qSerWthTWtaYb56M)が、それだと毎回自分で定義しないといけません。もちろんそれを自前のライブラリ化して `import` しても良いのですが、それよりラクな方法があるなら知りたいです。

- 組み込みの関数を使って **簡単に** 末尾を取れないのでしょうか？　たとえば `a.last(n)` のように末尾を取れないでしょうか。
- あるいは、適当な有名ライブラリに末尾を取るための関数があったりしないでしょうか？

環境: Python 3.6.5

Comment: 「`n > len(a)` のときは `a` を返す」というのは、「`a` と同じ要素を持つリストを返す」ということで大丈夫ですか？

Comment: @myj さん、はい、そう意図していました。コピーか参照かは今は特に考えていません。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

どうもイディオムは無さそうですね。
だとすると、やはり適切な名前で関数を定義するのがPython的かと思いますが、短く書く例も出しておきます。

```
# 意図が通じる限界か
a[max(0, len(a)-n):]

# False.__index__() == 0 を利用したもの
a[-n: n>0 and None]
```

Comment: 2つ目のやり方は、`True and None` だと `None` になるが、`False and None` だと `False` になるということですね。Python でもこういうトリッキーなことができるとは知りませんでした。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 7):

`collections.deque` を使う方法もあるかと思います。

```
>>> import collections
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> list(collections.deque(a, 2))
[5, 6]
>>> list(collections.deque(a, 0))
[]
>>> list(collections.deque(a, 8))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！　確かに [`deque`](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) を使うと n ≧ 0 で上手く動作し、n < 0 でエラー `ValueError: maxlen must be non-negative` を出すんですね。負値でエラーを出しますが、`a[-m:]` をそのまま使うよりかは直感的です。

Answer (score 2):

[metropolis さんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/46714/19110)を受けて考えている中で、三項演算子を使って書くとシンプルなことに気づきました。

```
# n が定義されているとして...
a[-n:] if n > 0 else []
```

末尾を取る操作がプログラム中に何回もあったり、メソッドチェーンで繋ぎたかったりするときには若干不便ですが、今回の自分の用途にはこれで充分そうです。

<sub>(自己回答できてしまいましたが、こんなことしなくてももっとシンプルに書けるよ、という方法があればご教示頂きたいです。)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

「後ろから何個」という指定と slice との相性が悪いので, リストをいったん逆順にする方針で考えてみました.

```
# a: リスト, n: 長さ
list(reversed(list(reversed(a))[:max(0, n)]))

# ↑だと文字数が多いので短縮
a[::-1][:max(0, n)][::-1]
```

ただし, 意図が分かりづらいですし, 複雑な処理ではないのに式が長くなってしまっています.

Comment: ありがとうございます。1つ目と比較して2つ目は、文字数が短縮されているだけでなく、[計算時間も変わっていますね](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3705705/5989200)。